# How can I count repeat rows in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to assign one unique number for each repeated row in select statement.

table
Name      | Position
Mark Wol        1
Mark wol        1
MArtha          1
Martha          1

and I want this

1    Mark Wl      1
2    Martha       1

Comment: Please post your code and a little more detail about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Google?

Comment: If I use google what is the point of this web?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as few or as many rows as you want. If you want to use all of the rows, list them all.

```
SELECT Row1, Row2, Row3, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY Row1, Row2, Row3, 
        ORDER BY Row1
    )
FROM Table
```

Comment: thanks this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to already have a unique ID for each record and then you are choosing to show that (which will come from the first found record)...

```
SELECT name,COUNT(*),id
FROM test_table
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```